# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_28

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
a=tf.Variable(1)
b=tf.Variable(1)


with tf.Session() as session:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    session.run(init_op)
```

For it, I am getting this error:

```
FailedPreconditionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f8326bc9e421> in <module>()
      6 with tf.Session() as session:
      7     init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
----> 8     session.run(init_op)
      9 
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    338     try:
    339       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 340                          run_metadata_ptr)
    341       if run_metadata:
    342         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    562     try:
    563       results = self._do_run(handle, target_list, unique_fetches,
--> 564                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    565     finally:
    566       # The movers are no longer used. Delete them.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    635     if handle is None:
    636       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
--> 637                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
    638     else:
    639       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
    657       # pylint: disable=protected-access
    658       raise errors._make_specific_exception(node_def, op, error_message,
--> 659                                             e.code)
    660       # pylint: enable=protected-access
    661 

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_28
```

I'm not sure what I did  wrong here.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you running this in ipython/ipython notebook by any chance?

Comment: lejlot question is good.  Also, what version of python and tensorflow?  Lastly, does this happen if you use global_variables_initializer ?

Comment: I'm doing the Big Data University course. The python version is `2.7.12` and the tensorflow version is `0.8.0`.

Comment: If I use `global_variables_initializer` I get this `'module' object has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'`

Comment: @octavian use current version (1.1)